# search exact match and highlight jquery datatable regex

Tags: jquery, regex, datatables

In jquery datatable, I have to filter the result with exact match and highlight it. for exact match I am trying following code but it does not work. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yg32o2yh/5/)

```
table.aoPreSearchCols[ iCol ].sSearch = "^\\s*"+'1'+"\\s*$";
table.aoPreSearchCols[ iCol ].bRegex = false;
table.aoPreSearchCols[ iCol ].bSmart= false;
```

Comment: Can describe _"it does not work"_ ? Appear to return match at http://jsfiddle.net/yg32o2yh/5/ ?

Comment: when I type "xon" then it is selecting first row. but in there is no word staring from "xon"

Comment: Is expected result that query `xon` _not_ match `Tiger Nixon` ?

Comment: yes, If my search text is begning  of the word then only it should appear. for example. I have two paragraph "my word has no limit" "it is unlimited". If I type limit then first paragraph should show and section should be hide

Comment: variable `iCol` appear to return `undefined` ? See `console` at jsfiddle

Comment: I took that example of code from the web

Comment: See post. Try including `RegExp` as parameter to `.search()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you need to use a [word boundary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), `\b` :

> Matches a word boundary. A word boundary matches the position where a
>   word character is not followed or preceeded by another word-character.

So when you have search term "*limit*" and the strings "*my word has no limit*", "*it is unlimited*" only the first string is a match. So

```js
$('#search-inp').keyup(function(){
    var term = $(this).val(),
        regex = '\\b' + term + '\\b';

    table.columns(1).search(regex, true, false).draw();
})
```

**Highlight**

Define some static "highlight tags" to inject and remove in order to highlight search matches :

```js
var hlBegin = '<strong class="highlight">',
    hlEnd = '</strong>';
```

Adding the highlight tags to column content :

```js
function highlight(term) {
    var row, str,
        rowCount = table.rows().nodes().length,
        regexp = new RegExp('('+term+')', 'ig');

    for (row=0; row<rowCount; row++) {
        str = table.cell(row, 1).data();
        str = str.replace(regexp, function($1, match) { 
           return hlBegin + match + hlEnd;
        })
        table.cell(row, 1).data(str).draw();
    }        
}
```

Removing highlight tags :

```js
function removeHighlight() {
    var row, str,
        rowCount = table.rows().nodes().length;

    for (row=0; row<rowCount; row++) {
        str = table.cell(row, 1).data();
        str = str.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, '');
        table.cell(row, 1).data(str).draw();
    }        
}
```

Setting it all together :

```js
$('#search-inp').keyup(function(){
    var term = $(this).val(),
        regex = '\\b' + term + '\\b';

    removeHighlight();
    table.columns(1).search(regex, true, false);
    highlight(term);
})
```

forked fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/Lnvbnp6c/**

---

**Update**. I got the impression (through comments) that whole words anywhere should be matched. If it is about matching a whole word in the beginning of the column :

```
regex = '^' + term + '\\b';
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/Lnvbnp6c/1/**

If it is just about matching characters the column begins with, not nessecarily a whole word :

```
regex = '^' + term;
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/Lnvbnp6c/2/**

The last one is probably the one users would like the most, when they are typing in the search field.

---

As an alternative approach you could try to use a custom filter :

```js
$('#search-inp').keyup(function() {
    var str,
        term = $(this).val(),
        regexp = new RegExp('\\b' + term + '\\b', 'ig');

    removeHighlight();    
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
        function(settings, data, dataIndex ) {
            str = data[1];
            return regexp.test(str) ? true : false;
        }     
    );
    table.draw();
    highlight(term);    
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop();
})
```

demo with highlight as above -> **http://jsfiddle.net/x96hzok4/**

My impression is that this is a little bit faster. Certainly, if you have a lot of rows, and want to search on multiple columns, I think you should consider a custom filter, and consider not to make time-consuming complete regular expressions on all strings.

Comment: Thanks a lot for nice answer. Just one more think. I checked fiddle attached by You. I need to modify word boundary. The regex should match world starting.

Comment: Like if I type"Tige". Then it should select first, I have remove the last '\\b' from the regex but when I am typing "T" then word have t between the word is also get highlighted

Comment: hey @amit, It was actually was I was started out with - but when I saw the comment : _I have two paragraph "my word has no limit" "it is unlimited". If I type limit then first paragraph should show and changed focus_.  See update for either exact match starting word, or just match starting characters ...Seems to be starting characters you really want.

Comment: fiddle with regex = '\\b' + term + '\\b' is seem to usefull for me. I removed the //regex = '\\b' + term  the last '\\b'.  when we type only one letter that it has a problem

Comment: @amit "_when we type only one letter that it has a problem_", yes, you have the problem that nothing compares to that single character ..? Or what is the problem? Funny you say it, I have thought about the same, that you should have a click-button instead of instant search, or perhaps a delay after keyup instead.

Comment: Hi, I've seen all your answers here. I was wondering if you could help me too? It's about filtering the gender in my table list. When I search for "Male", both Male and Female shows up. How will I do it that only records with gender Male will show up? Thank you so much, hope you can help me. So far this is just what I have. I have no idea how to do what I want. Please help me. https://jsfiddle.net/v0r4jr97/

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$('#search-inp').keyup(function(){
    var key = $(this).val();
    var regExp = "."
    if (key)
        regExp = "^\\s*" + key + "\\s*$";

    table.columns(1).search(regExp, true).draw();
});
```

When search `key` is empty always set it to `.` matches `any` in `regex`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  $('#search-inp').keyup(function(){
      var elem = $(this)
      table.columns(1)
      .search("^\\s*"+elem.val()+"\\s*$", true)
      .draw()
  });
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yg32o2yh/6/

See [column().search()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().search()) ; see also [$.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/$.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex())

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Your code is searching from beginning and end of paragraph. We can use \b either and it has problem when we are leaving blank in search text box

Comment: @amit Utilized `RegExp` at original post . Not certain interpret _"it has problem when we are leaving blank in search text box"_ correctly ? Can describe details ?

Comment: if you search something and if you remove the search text then all the list should visible to user but it is not happening

Comment: Is search for `Names` only ?

Comment: Yes, it is for name only