# Search DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I need to search on the [DataTable](https://www.datatables.net/reference/api/) and return true if a particular "string" has been found across the table. As starter I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/onelazy/Louyvwqp/1/). But it keeps on returning true and the value is always "found" even if there is nothing like it in the table. What am I doing wrong ?

```
if(table.columns().search("ddd"))
  {
    alert("found");
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    alert("not found");
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: `table.colums().search("textbox.text"); ` but there in `columns()` you must have to parse selected column index.

Comment: https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().search() here you found solution in this link. `Build a search for each column with a select-filter class.:` cheack this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [search exact match and highlight jquery datatable regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29783136/search-exact-match-and-highlight-jquery-datatable-regex/)

Comment: [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns().search()) search is done to filter out table column in datatables `column.search( this.value ).draw();` and in yours case `table.columns().search("ddd")` it will always be true

Answer (score 0):

In Datatable documentation, you can see this [Link](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().search()). According to this link, search result will be string if it is available on search and if there is no match it will return empty string.

So, in either way your condition will be true and you always get found alert. Also, your input has search ability, with `keyup` function. Why do you need it ?