# Search Exact Match R datatable

Tags: r, search, datatables, dt, exact-match

My issue is with the global search bar in the datatable package.

I'm trying to set this global search bar to find an exact match. There're some **java query** based instructions here:

[search exact match and highlight jquery datatable regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29783136/search-exact-match-and-highlight-jquery-datatable-regex)

However, I need to know how to do the same thing in **Rstudio**. I think I have to use JS() function, but, I'm not sure how to do it.

I came up with the "smart=FALSE" solution but it doesn't work for me.

Also, I can't use shiny app as we don't have it on my company's server.

Here is the dummy example:

```
library(DT)
f=data.frame(c(10,12,35),c('aa','ab','cc'))
colnames(f)<- c('Col1','Col2')
datatable(f)
```

If you type 'a' in the global search bar, you'll get 2 observations, where both includes 'a'. However, I would like to get no observation as there's no exact match for 'a' in the table.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Regards,

Adel

Answer (score 2):

This works only in a browser, not in the RStudio viewer:

```
js <- c(
  "function(settings){",
  "  var instance = settings.oInstance;",
  "  var table = instance.api();",
  "  var input = instance.parent().find('.dataTables_filter input');",
  "  input.off('keyup search input').on('keyup', function(){",
  "    var keyword = '\\\\b' + input.val() + '\\\\b';",
  "    table.search(keyword, true, false).draw();",
  "  });",
  "}"
)

datatable(iris[c(1,2,51,52,101,102),], 
          options = list(initComplete = JS(js))
)
```

[image]