# How to perform literal search in Shiny DataTable column filter?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, datatables, dt

This one has stumped me, and although I've looked into DataTables specific solutions ([jQuery DataTables - Filter column by exact match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609577/jquery-datatables-filter-column-by-exact-match)), I haven't yet identified how to achieve a JavaScript solution.

I need a literal match for column filters in my DataTable.  In the example that follows, that means returning just Mazda RX4 and not Mazda RX4 Wag.  Ideally this would apply to *any* DT search field. Here's an MRE with the formatting I'm using for this specific table:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(

    fluidRow(
      dataTableOutput("dt_tab")
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$dt_tab <- DT::renderDataTable({
    
    mtcars$car <- rownames(mtcars)

    DT::datatable(mtcars,
                  style = "bootstrap",
                  class = "display compact stripe cell-border wrap",
                  selection = "single",
                  callback=DT::JS('$(\'div.has-feedback input[type="search"]\').attr( "placeholder", "Search" )'),
                  rownames = FALSE,
                  filter = 'top',
                  extensions = 'Scroller',
                  options=list(columnDefs = list(list(visible=FALSE, targets=c(0))),
                               search = list(regex = FALSE, caseInsensitive = FALSE),
                               lengthChange = F,
                               scrollX = T,
                               scrollY = '60vh',
                               scroller = T,
                               paging = T,
                               initComplete  = JS(sprintf('function() {
                                   this.api().table().scroller.toPosition(%s);
                                   }', 0)),
                               dom = '<"top"if>rt<"bottom"lp><"clear">',
                               deferRender = TRUE,
                               language = list(searchPlaceholder = "across all columns")
                  )
    )
    
  }, server = TRUE)
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I know that a similar solution was posted here: [Search Exact Match R datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49291411/search-exact-match-r-datatable), but I can't seem to manage the right JavaScript.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it ok with the search builder?

```r
library(DT)

dat <- data.frame(
  car = c("Mazda", "Mazda RX4", "Mazda RX4 Wag", "Ford", "Mercedes"),
  day = Sys.Date() + 0:4
)

datatable(
  dat,
  extensions = c("SearchBuilder", "DateTime"),
  options = list(
    dom = "Qlfrtip",
    searchBuilder = TRUE
  )
)
```

[image]

#### Note: usage in Shiny

In order to use the search builder in a Shiny app, you have to set the option `server = FALSE` in the `renderDT` function. Server-side searching is not supported.

---

## EDIT

Here is a way without the search builder. It has an inconvenient: you have to specify the index of the column in which you want to search. That's because DataTables supports exact regex search only on a column basis.

```r
library(DT)

dat <- data.frame(
  car = c("Mazda", "Mazda RX4", "Mazda RX4 Wag", "Ford", "Mercedes"),
  day = Sys.Date() + 0:4
)

js <- c(
  "function(settings){",
  "  var instance = settings.oInstance;",
  "  var table = instance.api();",
  "  var input = instance.parent().find('.dataTables_filter input');",
  "  input.off('keyup search input').on('keyup', function(){",
  "    var keyword = '^' + input.val() + '$';",
  "    // we search in column 1",
  "    table.column(1).search(keyword, true, false).draw();",
  "  });",
  "}"
)

datatable(
  dat,
  options = list(initComplete = JS(js))
)
```

---

## EDIT

Finally, here is how to search an exact match in the column-wise filter boxes:

```r
library(DT)

dat <- data.frame(
  car = c("Mazda", "Mazda RX4", "Mazda RX4 Wag", "Ford", "Mercedes"),
  pet = c("dog", "dog", "cat", "cat", "cat"),
  day = Sys.Date() + 0:4
)

js <- c(
  "function(settings){",
  "  var instance = settings.oInstance;",
  "  var table = instance.api();",
  "  var $inputs = instance.parent().find('.form-group input');",
  "  $inputs.off('keyup search input').on('keyup', function(){",
  "    var keyword = '^' + $(this).val() + '$';",
  "    var index = 1 + $inputs.index(this);", # add 1 for the rownames column
  "    table.column(index).search(keyword, true, false).draw();",
  "  });",
  "}"
)

datatable(
  dat, filter = "top", 
  options = list(initComplete = JS(js))
)
```

[image]

---

## EDIT

If you delete the search with the previous solution, then it is not cancelled, you have to click the cross and this is not convenient. Here is a solution which doesn't have this inconvenient:

```r
js <- c(
  "function(settings) {",
  "  var instance = settings.oInstance;",
  "  var table = instance.api();",
  "  var $inputs = instance.parent().find('.form-group input');",
  "  $inputs.off('keyup search input').on('keyup', function() {",
  "    var value = $(this).val();",
  "    if(value !== '') {",
  "      var keyword = '^' + value + '$';",
  "      var index = 1 + $inputs.index(this);", # add one if row names
  "      var column = table.column(index);",
  "      column.search(keyword, true, false).draw();",
  "    }",
  "  });",
  "}"
)
```

Comment: The search builder is a great extension I was not aware of! I will certainly use it moving forward.  But for this project's purposes I do need a literal string match in the top search filter.

Comment: @AlanFarahani I have a way which *should* work but it doesn't. I've just opened [an issue here](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/1019).

Comment: And strangely enough, the search builder doesn't work for me in the way that you are showing.  I can provide an MRE. It doesn't show the dropdown menu nor does it filter the table.

Comment: @AlanFarahani Strange. Are you using an old version of DT?

Comment: @ Stéphane Laurent -- interesting!  I'll look forward to see what the solution is.  Otherwise I still can't the search builder to work with Shiny -- either in the R Studio window or in a browser.  I may open a separate post for that.

Comment: I'm using shiny 1.7.2 and DT 0.25 on R 4.2.1 patched

Comment: @AlanFarahani It seems that the method I showed in the Github issue works if one searches in a given column, but not the global search. You can try [here](https://datatables.net/examples/api/regex.html). Search e.g. ***Satou$*** (with regex on and smart off). It does not work globally, but it works if you search in the first column.

Comment: @AlanFarahani See my edit. And outside shiny, does it work?

Comment: Search builder works in R Markdown, but not in Shiny.  Is that worthy of opening a bug ticket in DT? ***

And the solution you provided works -- but it's still reliant on the global search bar, rather than using filter = 'top'.  In my case I need literal string matches (i.e. ^+val+$) in the filters beneath the column. ***

Would it be possible to target the column using something like "this.api().table().column(1).search"?

Comment: @AlanFarahani I opened a new question: <https://stackoverflow.com/q/73758445/1100107>.

Comment: Ah you want to search with the DT filters at top of the columns. I don't know...

Comment: @AlanFarahani I see: in **Shiny**, you have to set `server=FALSE` in `renderDT` in order for the search builder to work.

Comment: I found the solution.  Using your code, if we change the instance.parent().find to instance.parent().find('.form-group input');", that targets the filters underneath each column.  Would you mind editing your answer to reflect that?  Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: @AlanFarahani Let me try and I edit.

Comment: @AlanFarahani But what do you write instead of `table.column(1)`?

Comment: I changed nothing in your original code *except* for this line:  "  var input = instance.parent().find('.form-group input');",

Everything else is the same.  However I notice if you search in the bar, then delete the search, the table shows no rows!

Comment: The regex approach which you expect to work (using start and end anchors) - I think that applies across the entire data in the row, not field-by-field. I suppose perhaps that is an optimization in how DataTables implements its global search.

Comment: @AlanFarahani Instead of deleting the search, you have to click the cross to cancel it.

Comment: @AlanFarahani Yes but this works only in the first column. I found the final solution, see my edit.

Comment: Amazing, I appreciate your heroic efforts!  Just a note that the "cross" to cancel the search will not show up if server = T (i.e. it must = F) in *shiny*. And I suppose one way to incorporate backspace or delete is to add a conditional in the JS to not search if $(this).val() = "" or something along those lines. That's for a later time. Cheers.

Comment: @AlanFarahani I edited again. With this code, the search is cancelled when you delete it.

Comment: @AlanFarahani Could you please accept the answer? Otherwise your question is considered as non-answered.

Comment: It should have been accepted already.

Comment: And one last final note (in a very long comments section) -- if you are using shiny, you can not use this javascript with *any* kind of scrollX=T, scroller = T, or rownames = F.  It works fine with pagination, though.

Comment: @AlanFarahani It should work with `rownames=F`, but you have to remove the `1+` in the js code.