# Providing alternative search data to Datatables JS

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10

We have a table that contains a user's email address, their first name and last name and some date columns. The standard search works great for those.

I would like to provide a way of the user being searchable by their user id which is a GUID. The user id is not a visible piece of data. This search would really only be used by admins

I know I could use the data-search attribute on the user name column e.g.

data-search="**43**b30438-e3c8-4e27-8b31-5fcc**52**e53a3b me@test.com"

However that makes that row and any other row findable with just the number "43" as that GUID starts with 43 or "52" because it has a 5 followed by an 2. That is clearly not what I want. How do I make the users searchable by their GUID as well as their username but in the case of the GUID only when it is the whole GUID being searched for?

Thanks

Comment: One option is to use the approach shown in [Search an exact match in a DataTables table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73758445/12567365). That solution uses exact matches for every column. So you would need to adjust its logic and use the `index` parameter to determine when you are processing the GUID column vs. every other column. You can then specify the exact match logic for that one column, and use [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) for all the other columns.

Comment: Or, for the GUID column, you could use `startsWith()` instead of `===`, if that would be more useful.